# $\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=\inf_{x\in[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}}f(x)$ for a continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. I'm sure it's not hard, but I'm unsure what exactly we need to do to prove $$\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=\inf_{x\in[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}}f(x)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give a complete proof. First, since $$[a,b]\cap 
\mathbb{Q}
\subset \lbrack a,b]$$ then $$\inf_{x\in \lbrack a,b]}f(x)\leq \inf_{x\in
\lbrack a,b]\cap 
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
}f(x).$$ Let us prove the other inequality. Because of continuity of $f$ on $%
[a,b]$ then there exists some $x_{1}\in \lbrack a,b]$ such that $$%
f(x_{1})=\inf_{x\in \lbrack a,b]}f(x).$$ Density of $[a,b]\cap 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
$ into $[a,b]$ implies that there exists a sequence $(x_{n})_{n\geq 2}$ such
that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x_{n}=x_{1}$$ and $$x_{n}\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
$$ for any $n\geq 2.$ Therefore, $$\inf_{x\in \lbrack a,b]\cap 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
}f(x)\leq f(x_{n})$$ for any $n\geq 2.$ Passing to the limit one gets $$%
\inf_{x\in \lbrack a,b]\cap 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
}f(x)\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }f(x_{n})$$ and by continuity of $f$ at
the point $x_{1}$ it follows that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty
}f(x_{n})=f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }x_{n})=f(x_{1}).$$ That is: $$%
\inf_{x\in \lbrack a,b]\cap 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
}f(x)\leq \inf_{x\in \lbrack a,b]}f(x).$$ Which proves the required equality
in the title.

Comment: In your proof, you're using that a continuous function attains its infimum over a compact set. So, at a first glance, I thought it would be crucial that we're taking the infimum over $[a,b]$ instead of any subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$. However, if $(\Omega,\tau)$ is any topological space, $D$ is $\tau$-dense in $\Omega$, $\mathcal E$ denotes the Euclidean topology and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is $\tau$-$\mathcal E$-continuous, then $$\inf_\Omega f=\inf_D f\;.$$

Comment: Now, if $\tau$ is induced by a separable metric $d$, then any subset $A$ of $\Omega$, equipped with $\left.d\right|_{A\times A}$, is separable and hence contains a countable $\tau$-dense subset $D$. So, this should prove the desired result too. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $m_r=\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)$ and $m_q=\inf_{x\in[a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}}f(x)$ are different; necessarily $m_r<m_q$.

Necessarily by continuity there exists $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $m_q>f(x_0)>m_r$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ such that $\epsilon<m_q-f(x_0)$, then by density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and by continuity of $f$ there exists $q_0\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|f(q_0)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$. That leads us to conclude that $f(q_0)<m_q$ which is absurd.

Hence $m_r=m_q$.

Comment: I suppose $x_0$ exists by the *Intermediate value theorem*.

Comment: That is correct (assuming of course that we're not in the trivial case $a\ge b$) @0xbadf00d

Comment: Let $f(x)=x$ and $a=\sqrt{2}$.  Then $\inf_{[a,2]\cap Q}f(x)$ doesn't exist in Q.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I supposed that both infs existed in our case. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe $\inf_{[\sqrt{2},2]\cap\mathbb{Q}}x$ exists in $\mathbb{R}\;.$ I don't understand why you think that this answer is untrue in the case, where the infimum on the right hand side does not exist in $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $f$ is a mapping into $\mathbb{R}$, it's obvious that we understand the infimum with respect to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Clearly $m_{r}$ is minimum value of $f$ attained at say $x_{1}$ so that $f(x_{1}) = m_{r}$. However we can't say that there is a value $x_{2}$ such that $f(x_{2}) = m_{q}$. Hence the intermediate value theorem does not apply and thus we can't get the existence of $x_{0}$ via IVT.

Comment: The argument for existence of $x_{0}$ needs to be clearly mentioned. By definition of $m_{q}$ there is a rational $x_{2}$ such that $m_{q} \leq f(x_{2})$. Also since $m_{r}$ is minimum of $f$ so there is a real $x_{1}$ with $f(x_{1}) = m_{r}$. Thus we have $f(x_{1}) = m_{r} < m_{q} \leq f(x_{2})$ and hence by IVT there is an $x_{0}$ with $m_{r} = f(x_{1}) < f(x_{0}) < m_{q}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Why do you believe that $f(x_0)<m_q$? why not $f(x_0)$ between $m_q$ and $f(x_2)$?

Comment: @Idris: We have $f(x_{1}) = m_{r} < m_{q} \leq f(x_{2})$ and this means that for any number $K$ in interval $[f(x_{1}), f(x_{2})]$ (which contains the interval $[m_{r}, m_{q}]$) we have an $x$ with $f(x) = K$. I have chosen $K$ be in the open interval $(m_{r}, m_{q})$ and got $x_{0}$ with $m_{r} < K = f(x_{0}) < m_{q}$.